# Black screen after clicking "Install Ubuntu"

Tags: 12.04, installation, asus

I want to install the latest ubuntu (12.04.2 LTS) in my ultrabook asus S56C.

I tried to boot with USB & CD, but both stuck in black screen after choosing "Try Ubuntu..." or "Install Ubuntu"...

Need some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we are!

I fix this by disabling the "Secure boot" in the BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

May be your graphics card not detected by ubuntu. Try to install after connecting external monitor.

Comment: ok I will try, I will keep you informed

Comment: ok, I tried to connect an external screen monitor but nothing different happened. The new screen still in standby and the laptop keep displaying black screen. :/ There is  no any error or something to help me to know what is wrong :(